# sudoer file how to give a particular user full access to only certain file

Tags: files, permissions, users, privileges

I want to give a user full access to only certain files, can someone show me how to do that?  For example, I want to modify the sudoer file to grant user access to only certain file.  Thanks.

Comment: This is also off topic, but you shouldn't using sudo's file for this, but actually chown and chmod/ whatever works on your system. Flagged to be migrated to superuser

Answer (score 5):

you can do it using access control lists:

1)first, check the ACL of that file:

```
getfacl PATH/files
```

the output will be something like this:

```
# file: PATH/file
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

2)set the ACL of file in order to set full access permission for a specific user:

```
setfacl -m u:USERNAME:rwx PATH/file
```

3) now if you try "ls -l" command on your file, a plus(+) sign is added to the output:

```
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 root  root      0 Nov 10 20:12 file
```

4) get the ACL of file again to see the changes (Command is the same as step 1), the output will be like this:

```
# file: file
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:USERNAME:rwx
group::r--
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

you can see that an exception is been declared for your specific user to have a permission to this file that is different from owner user, owner group and others permissions.

I hope you get your problem solved soon :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is typically done using groups.

#### Ownership

Files have two owners: a user, and a group. For example:

```
$ ls -l file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo foo 6 Nov  9 15:37 file1.txt
```

Here, the user and group are both `foo`.

We can change file ownership using
[chown](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html). Note that the link links to a manpage for Linux, but `chown` is pretty standard so it will probably work. When in doubt, consult your OS's manual (`man chown`).

For example, changing the group to `bar`:

```
$ chown :bar file1.txt
$ ls -l file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo bar 6 Nov  9 15:37 file1.txt
```

Note that the `bar` group needs to exist. Further below you'll see how to add new groups.

#### Permissions

The permissions are as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r--
Tuuugggooo
```

where `T` is the type; for normal files this is `-`, for directories `d`, for symbolic links `l` etc.
The `uuu` are the user permissions: `rw-`: read, write. The `ggg` group permissions are also `rw-`. Everyone else (`ooo`) gets `r--`, or, read-only access.

We can change the permissions using [chmod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) (again, a Linux manpage, but chmod is pretty standard). If we wanted to remove the write permission for group `bar` from the file, we could do:

```
$ chmod g-w file1.txt
$ ls -l file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo bar 6 Nov  9 15:37 file1.txt
```

#### Adding a new group

You could add a group specifically for managing access to some files.
How this is done is platform dependent. For Linux, there is [addgroup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/groupadd.8.html):

```
addgroup bar
```

For FreeBSD, there is [pw](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pw&sektion=8). Check your Operating System manual for the correct command to use!

#### Adding users to groups

This again, is platform dependent. For FreeBSD, the `pw` command mentioned above handles this. For Linux, it is [usermod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html).

Users typically have a primary (or initial) group, and secondary (or supplementary) groups. The primary group is used when new files are created.

For linux, adding (`-a`) user `foo` to the secondary (`-G`) `bar` group is done like this:

```
$ usermod -G bar -a foo
```

Now, the next time user `foo` logs in, his/her groups will be updated. Use the `id` command ([Linux id](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html) / [FreeBSD id](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?id%281%29): pretty standard) to inspect the group membership:

```
$ id
uid=1000(foo) gid=1000(foo) groups=1000(foo),1001(bar)
```

Comment: Note that `addgroup` is a common Linux utility, but is not universal amongst other Unix-style operating systems. For example, the FreeBSD method to add a group would be `pw groupadd special`, and you'd use `pw usermod username -G special` to add that group to a user. The question doesn't mention any particular operating system, so it's best to provide portable solutions, or qualify your answer if it's limited to just one OS.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for the feedback, I updated the answer!

Comment: You could also use ACL (acces control list) for adding extra permission on file. It could be usefull when you can't change the group of a file. see setfacl and getfacl command. Morother, be carefull with this command because ACL can be disabled on filesystem and could lead to security issue if used to remove permission to specific user.

Comment: Actually let me clarify, it's not the files that needs permission per se, but the commands that are performed on the file, e.g. cp, sed, etc.  This will keep me from having to do something like this:

ProcessBuilder ntpProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
   "/bin/sh", "-c",
   "echo " + PUB_PASSWORD + "| sudo -S bash -c \"cp -f " + ntp_conf_file_temp + " " + ntp_conf_file + "; service ntp reload\""
   );

I don't want to hardcode the password.  Thanks.

Comment: Added another answer dealing with the sudo part. You'll need to run as root so you want to make it as tight as possible. The file copy would still need a group approach from this answer; you don't want to give your (presumably Java) program root access to `cp`, for obvious reasons. I'll update the other answer shortly with another approach.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, check `man sudo`, `man sudoers` etc.

Here's a Linux-only example on how to configure a sudoers file to execute the SYSV Linux service script as root.

Edit/create a sudoers file for the user (I'll use `theusername`):

```
visudo /etc/sudoers.d/theusername
```

The format is

```
# <user list> <host list> = <operator list> <tag list> <command list>
```

You'll want to add this line:

```
theusername ALL = (root:root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

It may be necessary to add the user `theusername` to the `sudo` group; see my other answer for details.

*UPDATE*

The OP (via comments) wants to execute this:

```
ProcessBuilder ntpProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/bin/sh", "-c",
    "echo " + PUB_PASSWORD + 
    "| sudo -S bash -c \"cp -f " + ntp_conf_file_temp + " " + ntp_conf_file +
    "; service ntp reload\"" );
```

This will require to set up file permissions to be able to override the `ntp_conf_file` which we'll assume is owned by root. See the other answer for details. 
However, here's an alternative solution, using a script, placed in `/etc/ntp-update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/cp /etc/managed-ntp/temp.conf /etc/ntpd/ntp.conf
/usr/sbin/service ntp reload
```

As you see, the file paths are harcoded for security.

To set it up, we edit the sudoers file for the user to give access to run this script as root:

```
theusername ALL = (root:root) NOPASSWD: /etc/ntp-update.sh
```

And create the directory:

```
mkdir /etc/managed-ntp
chmod 2775 /etc/managed-ntp
chown theusername:theusergroup /etc/managed-ntp
```

The `2` in `2775` is the `setgid` bit, which makes sure that files created in that directory are owned by the group of the directory. When running as root, this isn't really necessary, but may come in handy.

Now, the application can do this:

```
// Make sure you write ntp_conf_file_tmp in /etc/managed-ntp/temp.conf!    
ProcessBuilder ntpProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/usr/bin/sudo", "/etc/ntp-update.sh"
);
```

Comment: I read somewhere that you should create an empty file in sudoer.d, but rather create it else where and then copy it there.  Do you have a good example of how to modify the file in sudoer.d folder in shell script (I am assuming the optimal way is to modify a sudoers.d file and not sudoers file?  Also, can you create groups within the sudoers.d file directly as opposed to creating a group outside of it and then reference it inside the file?

Comment: Also, does ntp-update.sh have to use sudo and therefore include password?

Comment: @user270811 it's like I said: as root, `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/someusername`. See `man visudo` on your system. You should not access that file any other way. You can only reference groups in a sudoers file; you'll have to create them with `addgroup`. And no, `ntp-update.sh` does not need a password: the purpose of specifying `NOPASSWD` in the sudoers file is that you don't have to. You *call* `/etc/ntp-update.sh` *using* `sudo`; `/etc/ntp-update.sh` itself does not use sudo. Try calling it on the commandline first, you'll understand: `sudo /etc/ntp-update.sh`.